# How do I persist a ASP.NET Identity Claim on a cookie until logout?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I am making a ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses Identity. Part of the authentication consists of storing a claim in a cookie, without saving it to a database, since that claim must only last until the user logs out. This claim is added to the user identity after log out, and the value of the claim can be changed by the user at any point while he is logged in. To do this I am using the following code:

```
var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
var Identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
if (Identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "custom"))
{
    Identity.RemoveClaim(Identity.FindFirst("custom"));
}
Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("custom", "value", ClaimValueTypes.Integer32));
AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant =
            new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity), new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
```

This works fine for a while... but about ten minutes after the user logs in the claim is gone! How can I make the claim persist until logout?

Comment: storing in cookie may not be a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `SecurityStampValidator` that is configured in `Startup.Auth.cs` is wiping away your custom claims that are stored in the cookie.

You need to look on this bit of code in `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)`:

```
OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
```

Especially function passed `user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))`

You need to modify this method `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync` to restore your custom claims there as well if they were present on the cookie.

Comment: @yenkay Could you please post the code you changed to get it working? I have the same problem. But I don't understand what I should change to get it working.

Comment: @yaza, what they mean is..... because of the security feature, you may have to have a caching layer or a DB persistence layer for the claims, because if your set to validate SecurityStamp (which boots multiple logins out).... it will wipe claims every x amount of time (in the example he gave, it's 10 minutes).